# Don't send request to the server if content hasn't changed

Tags: feature-request, javascript, posting, ajax

For example, when you press "Save edits" on comment, the request will be send to the server, even though the content of the comment wasn't changed.

You can check the content before sending to reduce load a little bit (:

Comment: The amount of client-side code required to do that surely would exceed the amount of traffic saved by not sending a request to the server in these rare situations, no?

Comment: @forest no. They have to add just one additional check before sending.